# Wondering why my INDIRECT formula in excel works when I use a text string in the formula, but NOT when I use a reference instead?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm quite confused, since I don't think this should be possible.

This is what's happening:

If I input:

```
=INDIRECT("'[2. "&$G$1&" Distribution Module.xlsx]Recon(Grouping)'!$A$1",TRUE)
```

It works perfectly fine.

HOWEVER, if I put:

```
"'[2. "&$G$1&" Distribution Module.xlsx]Recon(Grouping)'!$A$1"
```

into cell `A1`, and use the formula `INDIRECT(A1,TRUE)`, I get a #REF error.

Shouldn't it be the exact same input? Why does the text string version work, but not when I put that same text into a cell and reference it?

Comment: is the target workbook open?

Comment: Yep, the target workbook is open. If it wasn't, I don't think the text string version of the formula would work either.

Comment: oh, did you put `=` in front of your string? ie `="'[2. "&$G$1&" Distribution Module.xlsx]Recon(Grouping)'!$A$1"`  if not the `$G$1` is passed as a string and not a cell reference.

Comment: As @ScottCraner saya; if the FORMULA is visible in A1, then you need to add the `=` before it to get the reference string instead (created of the formula). Put another way; the text shown in A1 should be possible to put (copy and paste text) between `"`-quotes in your `INDIRECT("...")`-formula -> AND by that -> get it to "work".

Comment: That solved it! Thank you Scott and Hannu!